# Shared PHP functions across multiple PHTML files

Tags: magento-enterprise, ee-1.12

I'm working on cleaning up some codes where the previous person wrote a whole bunch of PHP code in PHTML files. So, for example, I made the PHP code put in `list.phtml` as part of the overriden `List.php`.

Now, I'm looking at `view.phtml` for the product-view page, and it calls a lot of child HTMLs. In particular, I'm looking at `media.phtml` and `configurable.phtml`, where there is very similar set of PHP codes. How can I integrate these PHP codes into one place (similar to what I did with `List.php`), so that each of these PHTML can call the same function (for example, `getProductUrls()`)?

Additionally, is it possible to have variables available in `media.phtml` also available in `configurable.phtml` without having to call `getProductUrls()` twice (once in media and once in configurable)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put all your custom code in one helper and have it available everywhere by calling:

```
Mage::helper('alias')->doSomething($withSomeParameter);
```

Also you can use the registry to simulate "Global" variables.
Set a variable like this:

```
Mage::register('key', $value);
```

and read it anywhere later with:

```
Mage::registry('key');
```

Just make sure you don't set the same key twice. It won't work.

Comment: As an experiment - registering closures with `Mage::registry()`: https://gist.github.com/philwinkle/6526768

Comment: I'm reading Alan Storm's article on it, but any common pitfalls to watch out for with `Mage::registry`?

Comment: It's somehow similar to using a global variable. If you can avoid it, do it, if not...don't worry to much.